# Python - Pandas - Print 10 rows at a time while keeping them properly aligned

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-alignment

I'm using `pandas` to create a dataframe and printing 10 rows at a time. If the user responds yes to print more, then I print the next 10 rows. This works, but printing it in section ruins the alignment. I'm wondering if there's a way I can keep things aligned while still only printing 10 rows at a time.

```
start_row = 0
end_row = 10
print((df[start_row:end_row]).to_string(index=False))
    while end_row < max_rows:
        if user_input("Add More Results? (YES/NO)") == "yes":
            # Deletes the question after "yes" input to make a more readable list
            print("\033[A                             \033[A")

            start_row += 10
            end_row += 10
            print((df[start_row:end_row]).to_string(index=False, header=False))
        else:
            print("\n")
            break
    else:
        end_row = max_rows
        print("\nEnd of List\n")
```

[result looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0l08.png), an unaligned mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to format the output via `formatters`:

```
# Outside the loop
formatters = {col: (lambda x: f'{x:>{max(len(str(y)) for y in df[col]) + 2}}')
              for col in df.columns}

# In the loop
print(df[start_row:end_row].to_string(index=False, header=False, formatters=formatters))
```

**EDIT**: After some consideration I think this is a more robust version:

```
formatters = {col: (lambda x: str(x).rjust(max(len(str(y)) for y in df[col]) + 2))
              for col in df.columns}
```

This should align the output consistently to the right such that there are at least 2 blanks padding on the left (via `>` in the format string). You can of course change the `2` to anything you want.

With the sample frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0, 1, 1000, 1001], 'Col2': [0, 1, 10000, 10001]})
```

```
   Col1   Col2
0     0      0
1     1      1
2  1000  10000
3  1001  10001
```

this

```
start_row, end_row = 0, 2
print(df[start_row:end_row].to_string(index=False, header=False))
start_row, end_row = 2, 4
print(df[start_row:end_row].to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

leads to

```
 0  0
 1  1
 1000  10000
 1001  10001
```

whereas this

```
start_row, end_row = 0, 2
print(df[start_row:end_row].to_string(index=False, header=False, formatters=formatters))
start_row, end_row = 2, 4
print(df[start_row:end_row].to_string(index=False, header=False, formatters=formatters))
```

leads to

```
      0       0
      1       1
   1000   10000
   1001   10001
```

You can of course also use individual functions for each column. For example this

```
formatters = {'Col1': (lambda x: str(x).rjust(max(len(str(y)) for y in df['Col1']) + 2)),
              'Col2': (lambda x: str(x).ljust(max(len(str(y)) for y in df['Col2']) + 2))}
```

leads to

```
     0 0      
     1 1      
  1000 10000  
  1001 10001
```

Or you could only define functions for selected columns. But that has the potential to lead to an overall strange output, since the column widths accumulate from left to right.

Comment: This is getting me really close, but I'm still struggling. How would I apply the max length to just one column?

Comment: @robotherders I don't quite understand? Do you want to exclude certain columns from the procedure? Or if you want to apply it only to one column, say `ColX`, then you set `formatters = {"ColX": (lambda x: f'{x:>{max(len(str(y)) for y in df["ColX"]) + 2}}')`.

Comment: @robotherders Addition: You can use individual functions for each column (I just used one generic construct for all that seemed to fit what I thought you need). And you don't have to include all columns into the formatter dict. But I think that there's a good chance that exclusion of columns leads to a strange overall output.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear.

```formatters = {"ColX": (lambda x: f'{x:>{max(len(str(y)) for y in df["ColX"]) + 2}}')``` worked perfectly once I got my left pad in the columns correct. Thank you!

Comment: @robotherders Great! If you're happy with the answer it would be nice if you’d consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).